# Python import BeautifulSoup not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import

I have a Python script that wants to use BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When I run the script from the command line, it works fine. When I run the script externally, from a browser, it dies on that line. The web logs say:

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I've also tried, with the same result:

```
import bs4
import BeautifulSoup
```

I installed the module from a tarball, and it now resides in a folder that is in my Python path:

```
/usr/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I have made sure the permissions for the `bs4` directory, and all .py and .pyc files in the folder allow execution (`chmod 775 *.py`), and I've checked to see that both internally and externally the same version of Python is being run (`2.7.9 (default, Jan 12 2015, 16:33:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]]`)

Comment: "When I hit the script from a web server" -- then your web server doesn't have beautifulsoup installed

Comment: Your Web server is not running as your user, and the folder in which you have installed BeautifulSoup is not in the PYTHONPATH for that user.

Comment: did you install `beautifulsoup` or `beautifulsoup4`? (should be the latter)

Comment: I'm sorry, that was unclear: clarified to say that I'm running it externally, from my browser. @AnttiHaapala, it is beautifulsoup4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robᵩ (phi) for pointing out what was wrong: because this script was on a shared server, I was unable to give execute permission to the "user" running the web server (in this case, "nobody"). I *was* able to run the script using ssh, since I was the user in that case.

Because I was unable to convince the hosting service to install `BeautifulSoup` for all users, I ended up using a different library, `lxml.html`, which my host server does install with Python.

(I found `lxml.html` a pleasure to work with, as well)

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed BeautifulSoup for the benefit of all the users on your computer. Instead, you installed only for the benefit of the user named "myName". In particular, you haven't installed it for the use of the user that runs the web server (often named 'www' or 'www-data').

If you can, install BeautifulSoup in the system-wide location.

Otherwise, you can modify your script like so:

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = ['/usr/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/']
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Hmm, that did not work for me. Your explanation makes sense though, and I will attempt to install it system-wide.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer is correct, as you pointed out what I had done wrong. But the script modification you offered never worked for me.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer correct or, even better, write an answer yourself that precisely describes what you did to solve the problem. You can then accept your own answer, since it will be more correct than mine.